# insert html markup to php html string

Tags: php

I'm using a builtin method that returns an html string:

```
var $stuff = $this->getBlock();
```

Where $stuff is:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<ul>
    <li>Foo<span>Bar</span></li>
    <li>Foo<span>Bar</span></li>
    <li>Foo<span>Bar</span></li>
    .
    .
    .
</ul>
```

What I'd like to do is add two more list elements to the end of that list. How can I do that? Would I just tokenize $stuff? Or is there a easier way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: See how $this->getBlock() build this items, or post code here

Comment: Did you check out DOMElement? http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php

Comment: you want to insert tags after </ ul > tags ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the following DOM functions/classes in PHP:

[The DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

[DOMDocument::createElement](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php)

Here's an example of how to do what you are asking:

```
$stuff = "<p>Lorem ipsum</p><ul><li>Foo<span>Bar</span></li><li>Foo<span>Bar</span>  </li><li>Foo<span>Bar</span></li></ul>";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($stuff);

$element1 = $dom->createElement('li', 'test');
$element2 = $dom->createElement('li', 'test');

$list = $dom->getElementsByTagName('ul');

$list->item(0)->appendChild($element1);
$list->item(0)->appendChild($element2);

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

You can replace $stuff with

```
$stuff = $this->getBlock();
```